# reduce the size of a javascript array while keeping members that are evenly distributed in the original

Tags: javascript

Hard to put into words but I am looking for a function that takes an array and reduces it down to a given size. The use case is specifying ticks for graph in d3.

```
 const availableDatetimes: Date[] = [...]
 const numberOfXTicks = chartWidth / 80
 const tickValues = reduceArrSize(availableDatetimes, numberOfXTicks)
```

the result should have evenly distributed dates

Comment: So how should it reduce the size? Remove some dates?

Comment: @kellys yes... need to keep an even distribution. assume the values in the array are uniformly distributed originally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called it `shrinkArray()`, because reducing an array is the name of a different well-defined operation. Here it is:

```
const shrinkArray = (array, size) => {
    const step = array.length / size
    return array.filter((v, i) => Math.floor(i % step) == 0)
}
```

Let's shrink an array of size 100 to size 33:

```
const originalArray = (new Array(100).fill(0)).map((v, i) => i)

const shrunkenArray = shrinkArray(originalArray, 33)
console.log(shrunkenArray);
console.log(shrunkenArray.length == 33);
```

So:

```
[
   0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,
  12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
  24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
  36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,
  48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59,
  60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71,
  72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83,
  84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95,
  96, 97, 98, 99
]
```

is shrunken to:

```
[
   0,  4,  7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25,
  28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 43, 46, 49, 53,
  56, 59, 62, 65, 68, 71, 74, 77, 80,
  83, 86, 89, 92, 95, 98
]
```

that is of size 33.

In this example the array is integers from 0 to 99, but obviously the function works for any data type.

Comment: You can also add ` if (array.length <= size) return array;` as the first line of the function, since in that case there's no need to filter. Although even without this line it works the same, it's just wasted computation.

Comment: would it be worth adding Math.floor to the step calculation so it is `const step = Math.floor(array.length / size)`. in any case I will accept this as it is almost exactly what I used. thank you

Comment: @JoeyGough *No* if you add that then there's no guarantee to get the exact size you want. For example if the array length is 100 and you want to shrink it to 30 you'll have `step = Math.floor(100/30) = 3` which will give you an array of size 34.